# How can I change dense layer to conv2D layer in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I want to classification for pictures with different input sizes. I would like to use the following paper ideas.

'Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation'
https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Long_Fully_Convolutional_Networks_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf

I did change the dense layer to conv2D layer like this.

```
def FullyCNN(input_shape, n_classes):

inputs = Input(shape=(None, None, 1))

first_layer = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(12,16), strides=1, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='conv1')(inputs)
first_layer = BatchNormalization()(first_layer)
first_layer = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(first_layer)

second_layer = Conv2D(filters=24, kernel_size=(8,12), strides=1, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='conv2')(first_layer)
second_layer = BatchNormalization()(second_layer)
second_layer = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(second_layer)

third_layer = Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,7), strides=1, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='conv3')(first_layer)
third_layer = BatchNormalization()(third_layer)
third_layer = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(third_layer)

fully_layer = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=8, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(third_layer)
fully_layer = BatchNormalization()(fully_layer)
fully_layer = Dropout(0.5)(fully_layer)
fully_layer = Conv2D(n_classes, kernel_size=1)(fully_layer)
output = Conv2DTranspose(n_classes, kernel_size=1, activation='softmax')(fully_layer)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
return model
```

and I made generator for using fit_generator().

```
def data_generator(x_train, y_train):
      while True:

          index = np.asscalar(np.random.choice(len(x_train),1))
          feature = np.expand_dims(x_train[index],-1)
          feature = np.resize(feature,(-1,feature.shape))
          feature = np.expand_dims(feature,0) # make (1,input_height,input_width,1) 
          label = y_train[index]
          yield (feature,label)
```

and These are images about my data.

[image: y_train_onehot_img]

[image: y_train_img]

However, there is some problems about dimension. 
Since the output layer must have 4 dimensions unlike the original CNN model, dimensions do not fit in the label.

Model summary:

[image: My model summary_img]

Original CNN model summary:

[image: Original CNN model summary img]

How can I handle this problem? I tried to change dimension about label by expanding the dimension.

```
label = np.expand_dims(label,0)
label = np.expand_dims(label,0)
label = np.expand_dims(label,0)
```

I think there is a better way and I wonderd that is it necessary to have conv2DTranspose? And should batch size be 1?

Comment: 1) Your model summary from the image is different from the model inferred from your code 2) what you refer to as "change" is unclear (what was the original configuration?) 3) in image classification settings, the norm is for the last layer to be a *dense* one, with units equal to the number of classes, and certainly not a convolutional one. Your whole question is completely unclear... (please see also why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode))

Comment: @desertnaut My model summary is same with my code. When you read the paper I mentioned, you will know what I mean.

Comment: You are right in that (my mistake); but the idea here at SO is certainly *not* "go read the linked paper"...

Comment: @desertnaut I want to change the dense layer into a convolution layer, as I mentioned in the title, rather than implement all the ideas in the paper. Anyway, thank you for your answer, If you think of a good idea, please let me know.

Comment: did u find a solution?